# Get Css Value Width in % - Selenium WebDriver- JUnit

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have a web page which displays a dynamic layout (generated by extjs) which is supposed to occupy 100% of the width.
I am using

> WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen4"));
>
> String backgroundColor = element.getCssValue("width");

But currently it is returning the width in pixel and on top that the WebDriver browser (Firefox) is not displayed in maximum mode so the value is even less.
Is there any way I can get the value in %? I came to know of some GetCssProperty class but I am unable to use it properly. Any details on that?
I am using Selenium WebDriver 2.23 with JUnit.

I guess there must be a way to maximize the window.

Comment: "I haven't looked into it." you even admit that?

Comment: @Frank: Sorry for confusing you folks but my question was about finding the width Css property of a div or anything in % like 100% or 60%. Currently the getCssValue returns the width in pixel.

Comment: if you mean [that](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_width_percent) please add it to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Slanec said you can maximize your window like

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

Than you can create a method

```
private float getWidthInRelationToWindow(WebElement element){
    return ((float)element.getSize().getWidth())/
                  this.drivy.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My faith in Stack Overflow is justified. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usi this to maximize:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

or even this for fullscreen:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

You can't get the value other than in pixels - you'll have to compute the percentage yourself. Note that you don't even have to use the CSS value, there's a [`getSize()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize%28%29) method on a `WebElement` which can be also used to get the size of `<html>` or `<body>` elements, you wouldn't then even need the maximize.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the question I was asking. Sorry for confusing you guys. I want to find the **width CSS property** of a div in %. Currently it returns the value in pixel which renders my test useless in a different system or resolution.

Comment: Any idea how can I compute the width in percentage?? Correct me if I am wrong - I get size of the html body, the size of the div and calculate??? Write a function for it??

Comment: @MaitreyaDwaipayan As I said, you'll need to calculate it yourself. Just divide the width by the window's (or containing element's) width. Use either `getCssValue("width")` or `getSize().width` I gave you.